# Merging Two Chronological Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables, production and sales, and trying to merge the tables into one table.

[image]

I can get to merge the table like below, but it doesn't include the month with just sales number.
How can I fill the production with zero for the month with just sales number.

```
select
EXTRACT(year from s.Date) as Year,
EXTRACT(month from s.Date) as Month,
p.Quantity as Production,
s.Sales
FROM Prodcution p, Sales s
WHERE
EXTRACT(year from s.Date) = EXTRACT(year from p.Date)
AND EXTRACT(month from s.Date) = EXTRACT(month from p.Date)
```

Comment: 1st of all what is s.Sales (there is no column with the name of Sales), is it s.Quantity?. 2nd is it possible that product quantity is 0 on someday and sale quantity is >0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery, I wouldn't separate out the year and month columns.  I would instead use `date_trunc()` to get the first day of the month.  This would look like:

```
select date_trunc(date, month) as yyyymm,
       coalesce(p.quantity, 0) as production,
       coalesce(s.sales, 0) as sales
from production p full join
     sales s
     using (date)
order by date;
```

You can, of course, split the year and month into separate columns.  However, I don't see that as useful.

I should note that you seem to have rows for every month for `sales`, but not for `production`.  That suggests that a `left join` is sufficient:

```
select date_trunc(date, month) as yyyymm,
       coalesce(p.quantity, 0) as production,
       coalesce(s.sales, 0) as sales
from sales s left join
     production p
     using (date)
order by date;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `full outer join` as follows:

```
select EXTRACT(year from coalesce(s.Date,p.date)) as Year,
       EXTRACT(month from coalesce(s.Date,p.date)) as Month,
       coalesce(p.Quantity,0) as Production,
       coalesce(s.Sales,0)
  FROM Prodcution p
  full outer join Sales s
   on EXTRACT(year from s.Date) = EXTRACT(year from p.Date)
  AND EXTRACT(month from s.Date) = EXTRACT(month from p.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with dates as (
  select extract(year from date) year, extract(month from date) month 
  from (
    select date_trunc(min(date), month) min_date, date_trunc(max(date), month) max_date
    from (
      select date from `project.dataset.production` union all 
      select date from `project.dataset.sales`)
  ), unnest(generate_date_array(min_date, max_date, interval 1 month)) date
)
select d.year, d.month, ifnull(p.quantity, 0) production, ifnull(s.quantity, 0) sales  
from dates d
left join `project.dataset.production` p
on d.year = extract(year from p.date) and d.month = extract(month from p.date) 
left join `project.dataset.sales` s
on d.year = extract(year from s.date) and d.month = extract(month from s.date) 
-- order by year, month
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: above solution can look from first glance as a little overengineering - NUT it covers case when there is gap not only in production table (as it is in sample data) but also if the gap is in sales table